# Disabling hyphen in words with underscores

Tags: hyphenation, underscore

I have words with underscores in my document. At the moment, those words are hyphenated and I'm almost happy with the result. But I would prefer these words to wrap to the next line without a hyphen. It will allow people to select the word without an extra symbol.

Comment: These sound like special words that may have a different formatting. Is that correct? Can you provide a complete minimal example that we can use as a foundation for providing solutions?

Comment: Please provide a couple of specific examples of words that contain underscores. And please tell us more about how you're typesetting them right now.

Comment: Depending on your exact setup, `\mbox{word\_with\_underscores}` might be sufficient to prevent hyphenation.